# Combining rows and generating category counts

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to be able to first combine rows with a similar attribute into one(for example, one row for each City/Year), and then find the specific counts for types of categories for each of those rows.

For example, with this as the original data:

```
City     Year   Type of Death
NYC      1995      Homicide
NYC      1996      Homicide
NYC      1996      Suicide
LA       1995      Suicide
LA       1995      Homicide
LA       1995      Suicide
```

I want to be able to produce something like this:

```
City     Year   n_Total   n_Homicides n_Suicides
NYC      1995      1            1       0       
NYC      1996      2            1       1
LA       1995      3            1       2
```

I've tried something like the below, but it only gives me the n_Total and doesn't take into account the splits for n_Homicides and n_Suicides:

```
library(dplyr)
total_deaths <- data %>%
  group_by(city, year)%>%
  summarize(n_Total= n())
```

Comment: Hi tatiwawa, welcome to Stack Overflow! You're almost there... 
`library(dplyr)`
`total_deaths <- data %>%` 
`group_by(city, year) %>%`
`summarize( n_Total = n(), n_Homicides = sum(\`Type of Death\` =="Homicide"), n_Suicides = sum(\`Type of Death\` == "Suicide"))`
`

Comment: thank you for this, this was perfect! i was so close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have too many types of death, then something simple (albeit a little "manual") like this might have some appeal.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'City     Year   TypeofDeath
NYC      1995      Homicide
NYC      1996      Homicide
NYC      1996      Suicide
LA       1995      Suicide
LA       1995      Homicide
LA       1995      Suicide')

df %>%
    group_by(City, Year) %>%
    summarize(n_Total = n(),
              n_Suicide = sum(TypeofDeath == "Suicide"),
              n_Homicide = sum(TypeofDeath == "Homicide"))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'City'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   City [2]
#>   City   Year n_Total n_Suicide n_Homicide
#>   <chr> <int>   <int>     <int>      <int>
#> 1 LA     1995       3         2          1
#> 2 NYC    1995       1         0          1
#> 3 NYC    1996       2         1          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you, I was so close! this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks to @AnilGoyal for supplying the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'City     Year   TypeofDeath
NYC      1995      Homicide
NYC      1996      Homicide
NYC      1996      Suicide
LA       1995      Suicide
LA       1995      Homicide
LA       1995      Suicide')

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = TypeofDeath, values_fn = length, values_from = TypeofDeath, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = 'n_') %>%
  mutate(n_total = rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with('n_'))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   City   Year n_Homicide n_Suicide n_total
#>   <chr> <int>      <int>     <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 NYC    1995          1         0       1
#> 2 NYC    1996          1         1       2
#> 3 LA     1995          1         2       3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can first dummify your factor variable using the `fastDummies` package, than `summarise()`. This is a more general and versatile approach that can be used seamlessly with any number of unique types of death.

If you only have two types of death and will settle for a simpler (though more "manual") approach, you can use the other suggestions with `summarise(x=..., y=..., total=n()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fastDummies)

df%>%fastDummies::dummy_cols('TypeofDeath', remove_selected_columns = TRUE)%>%
        group_by(City, Year)%>%
        summarise(across(contains('Type'), sum),
                  total_deaths=n())

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   City [2]
  City   Year TypeofDeath_Homicide TypeofDeath_Suicide total_deaths
  <chr> <int>                <int>               <int>        <int>
1 LA     1995                    1                   2            3
2 NYC    1995                    1                   0            1
3 NYC    1996                    1                   1            2
```